# How to write a simple self join query to find result by comparing it self?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let me being honest, I am Java developer assigned with this SQL development work where I need to list out all the **orderId** which having **nodeName** 'Delay' and **id** is 'MAX(id)'

| id | orderId | nodeName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Rain |
| 2 | 2 | Summer |
| 3 | 2 | Delay |
| 4 | 2 | Winter |
| 5 | 5 | Rain |
| 6 | 5 | Delay |
| 7 | 5 | Summer |
| 8 | 5 | Winter |
| 9 | 3 | Rain |
| 10 | 3 | Summer |
| 11 | 3 | Delay |
| 12 | 1 | Rain |
| 13 | 1 | Delay |
| 14 | 1 | Summer |
| 15 | 1 | Delay |

In above example it should fetch orderId 3 and 1 and ignore rest of the all orderId.
I know few might think it's a silly question but I have not much experience on SQL queries so I raised it on this forum.

Comment: `select distinct 
t1.orderid
from
table as t1
where t1.nodeName='Delay'
and not exists
(select id from table as t2 where t2.orderid=t1.orderid and t2.id>t1.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to list out all the orderId which having nodeName 'Delay' and id is 'MAX(id)'

One approach is aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select orderid
from t
group by orderid
having max(id) = max(case when nodename = 'Delay' then id end);
```

Or, if you do use a correlated subquery, `not exists` comes to mind:

```
select orderid
from t
where t.nodename = 'Delay' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.orderid = t.orderid and
                        t2.nodename <> 'Delay' and
                        t2.id > t.id
                 );
```

Comment: I followed the 1st approach and got the expected output. Thank you Gordon.

Answer (score 2):

Use a correlated subquery to check if the last `id` of each `orderId` has `nodeName = 'Delay'`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.orderId
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.nodeName = 'Delay'
  AND t1.id = (SELECT MAX(t2.id) FROM tablename t2 WHERE t2.orderId = t1.orderId)
```

Or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.orderId
FROM tablename t1
WHERE 'Delay' = (
  SELECT t2.nodeName 
  FROM tablename t2 
  WHERE t2.orderId = t1.orderId
  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
)
```

Or, with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT orderId
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY orderId ORDER BY id DESC) rn
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE rn = 1 AND nodeName = 'Delay'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1b29ad90378ab150951be0b3c29838f9).

Comment: Good  job here :)  :)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav now I saw that my 1st query with NOT EXISTS was already posted by you in a comment under the question. I removed it and you can post it as an answer.

Comment: It's all good.  Was just a Friday giggle :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are searching for only one row,
try:

```
SELECT MAX(id), orderId, nodeName
FROM table_name
WHERE nodeName = 'Delay';
```

If you are not searching for only one row, but for the results with the highest id,

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE nodeName = 'Delay'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following query

```
select t1.orderId
from tablename t1
join (SELECT MAX(id) as id FROM tablename group by orderId) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.nodeName = 'Delay'
```